# Not getting response using an express proxy server when parsing body

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, proxy-server

I have 2 servers and 1 proxy server. All running on express. I am facing a problem where I am not getting a request back when I use this in one of the servers :

```js
// Server 1
app.use(express.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

If I remove it, it works fine but the problem is that I don't want to remove it. I think its because my proxy server parses the body, but then I send the same content-type that I received from the request headers, but Im not sure.

Down below is my code :

**Proxy Server index.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const cors = require('cors');
const { router } = require('./routes');

const app = express();
dotenv.config();

const port = process.env.PORT || '3099';

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(router);

app.listen(3099, () => {
    console.log('Server listnening on port 3099');
});
```

**Proxy server routes.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const registry = require('./registry.json');

const router = express.Router();

router.all('/:apiName/:path?', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const method = req.method;
        const body = req.body;
        const headers = req.headers;
        const apiName = req.params.apiName;
        const path = req.params.path || '';
        if (registry.services[apiName]) {
            const response = await axios({
                method,
                url: registry.services[apiName].url + path,
                headers,
                data: body,
            });
            res.json(response.data);
        } else {
            res.status(404).json({
                error: 'Api is not registered in the registry !',
            });
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: `Proxy server error : ${err}` });
    }
});

module.exports = { router };
```

**Server 1 index.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const { router } = require('./router');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

// When I include this in here, it doesnt return a response
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const data = req.body;
    res.status(200).json(data);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server 1 listnening on port 3000');
});
```

EDIT : **I fixed the problem. The problem was that I was parsing the data in the proxy server but in the headers I was sending the old 'content-length' which was not accurate**

Comment: it's odd that you don't use `router` in that last code

Comment: With express you can make certain routes have a middleware, and others not.   Instead of putting `express.json` etc on your app, just create another route that has the required middlewares and attach the methods etc that require it to this one, your proxy route will then be untouched before passing on.  IOW: Currently your saying every method has these middleware running, when it's not what you need / require.  Another slight advantage too, is that there would be a slight performance increase as your not processing middlewares that are not required.

Comment: the problem then is that the routes that use this express.json wont work. Its something to do with the headers I am sending, because If I exclude them from the axios request I send in Proxy Server routes.js it is working properly